# Pass controller method to directive with isolated scope

Tags: angularjs

Hello i have a controller that uses various services like **$http**, **$scope**, **$window**.  Now i have also a directive with an **isolated scope**.  I am aware i can easily pass a controller method to a directive but i would like to know about the services.  Supposing the method in my controller uses both the $http and $window service or some other custom service when i pass it to my directive are those services passed **along with it**? If not then how can i pass those services along with the method to my directive.

Comment: No. You still have to inject the service into you directive, if you were to use them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The services you wish to use need to be injected into your directive.

```
.directive('directiveName', ["$injectedService", "$window", "$http", function($injectedService, $window, $http) {
  return {
    ... your directive code here ...
  };
}]);
```

You can find information about directives in the angular docs.
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive